# MVC and Web Api infrastructure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want to use MVC and Web API together and want the infrastructure as follows :

These all projects should be independent

1. MVC project

---- Here only views should be there. A view/response should be returned from Web API project

2. Web API Project

---- Here only controllers and models should be present.

3, DAL Project

---- Database essentials

So, how can make this infrastructure ? Can I call the controller residing in Web API project from MVC project ?

Thanks !
David

Comment: yes using ajax call and return the data in json

Comment: take a look at this site http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Create one blank solution.(New Project>Other Project Types>Visual studio solution>Blank Solution)
> 2. Add one new project of type class Library. This would be your Data Access Layer.
> 3. Add new Project for your MVC application.
> 4. Add new project for web api.

For more detail please check following tutorial. I hope it will help you to determine how to communicate with web api.

http://dotnetmentors.com/mvc/web-api-in-mvc-tutorial.aspx